# MariaDB 10.3.38 Giving syntax error while deleting using Common Table Expression

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I am trying to delete some data in my table using CTE , but its showing syntax error.
Only delete statement doesn't seem to work, if I use only select query instead of delete, it does work..

CODE

```
With results AS
    (Select * from table1 where time<='04:38:24' limit 10),
    results2 AS
    (Select UserId from table2 where address in (select * from results)),
    results3 AS
    (Select id from table4 where username in (Select * from results2))
    Delete from table3 using table3 join results3 on table3.column_id=results3.id;
```

ERROR

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Delete from table3 using table3 join results3 on `n...' at line 13
```

NOTE

1. table4 and table3 has a foreign key refernce.
2. When I use the same code in workbench it doesnt give any error, the error is only on MariaDB CLI.

I tried to use the delete statement using CTE, but it shows a syntax error.
The code was expected to delete data from table3, which is not happening due to the error..

Answer (score 0):

**update:**

I apologize I was confused and missed the part where you mentioned that the code works in workbench but not in the CLI.
It could be an issue with the CLI itself -- it could be that it's not recognizing `;` at the end of the delete so maybe you need to specify a different delimiter like `//`

```
DELIMITER //
WITH results AS (
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time <= '04:38:24' LIMIT 10
), results2 AS (
    SELECT UserId FROM table2 WHERE address IN (SELECT * FROM results)
), results3 AS (
    SELECT id FROM table4 WHERE username IN (SELECT * FROM results2)
)
DELETE FROM table3 USING table3 JOIN results3 ON table3.column_id = results3.id//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It still gives the same error as before..

Comment: I made an update~